# "click html /deep/ #id" not working in MeteorJS template event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, meteor, polymer

i want to trigger click event on shadow-dom polymer element

`document.querySelector("html /deep/ #main-toolbar-toggle")` is correctly pick the corresponding shadow-dom polymer element but `"click html /deep/ #main-toolbar-toggle": function(event, target) {` in meteor template event handler is not work

```
Template.layout_linto.events({

"click html /deep/ #main-toolbar-toggle": function(event, target) {
    alert("ok");
```

what r the correct syntax to do it using meteor template event handler ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a selector in relation to the template not the page. The template is in a scope that cannot access the page's html.

This is better:

```
Template.layout_linto.events({

"click #main-toolbar-toggle": function(event, target) {
    alert("ok");

}});
```

Comment: PolymerJS shadow DOM required /deep/